# Asynchronous process to consume items from queue and send them to external API

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, queue

I have a requirement: taking items from a queue and send them to an external API. And keep doing that process without waiting for the response from external API. For now, I let the class implements Runnable and in the run method I dequeue the items and send them. Then I use Excutor.newCachedThreadPool() to handle that process. I am not sure it is right or not. Any suggestion or correction?

Comment: Also, have a question about which one is better to implement this, Runnable or Callable?

Comment: Callable can return Object and can throw exception whereas Runnable cant so it basically depends on your requirement on what to use.

Comment: Using Executor makes sense when you have many small tasks. But you have a single  long task, so it is logical to run it in a dedicated thread, rather than submit to an executor.